# jquery attribute selected not working sometimes

Tags: jquery, html, select

I am trying to update selected value of html select using jquery based on condition

```
$inputName = $(this).attr('input-name');
$("#input-name-edit option").each(function() {
  $(this).removeAttr('selected');
  if($(this).text()==$inputName) {
    $(this).attr('selected',true);

  }
});
```

and in element it is clearly telling that Number of people is selected. but as you can see in below image Name which is first element is selected.

Also this is not always. sometime it is not working. i tried putting autocomplete attribute to off as well but still not displaying.

[image: select not working]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `value` of `select` element instead of manipulating `selected` attribute:

```js
var $select = $('#select');

function select(val) {
  $select.val(val)
}

$('button').on('click', function(){
  var val = $('input').val();
  select(val)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='select'>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
  <option value="d">d</option>
</select>

<input type="text" placeholder='Type value'>
<button>Change value</button>
```

Comment: thanks t1m0n. this is alternate, not the exact answer I am looking for. I have already used one alternate which is registering the select to DOM again after changing the selected value.